# List of organizations for authenticated user , how to add the scopes for this api?

Tags: flutter, github, firebase-authentication, github-organizations

i tried firebase authentication using GitHub in my flutter project. i got access token from it but i struggle to get organizations list of autheticated user using this token

link of this https://docs.github.com/en/rest/orgs/orgs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-organizations-for-the-authenticated-user

[Postman Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFen0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQziu.png)

Comment: Please [review this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) on "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?"

Answer (score 0):

You need your token to have 'repo' scope. When you create a classic token, you can choose what scope it will have. in this case your current token does not cover the scope of the repository.

You need to create a new token with that scope.

Comment: Yes, That I don't know how , but i got answer now , i need to pass the scope while signup. Thanks for your answer